# NullPointerException in DialogFragment on setAdapter() of a list

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment, listview-adapter

I create a custom DialogFragment. It contains a listView, but when the list calls setAdapter there is a NullPointerException. I can't understand why.
This is the code:

```
public class LineUpConfirm extends DialogFragment {

    private ListView list;
    private List<ItemLineUpConfirm> pList = new ArrayList<ItemLineUpConfirm>();
    private AdapterListConfirmLineUp adapter;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_lineup_layout, null));

        pList.add(new ItemLineUpConfirm("P", "C. Abbiati","MIL","INT"));
    pList.add(new ItemLineUpConfirm("D", "C. Papastapopulos","SAS","VER"));
    pList.add(new ItemLineUpConfirm("C", "Cacca","SAM","GEN"));

    adapter = new AdapterListConfirmLineUp(CurrentContext.getContext(),
            R.layout.item_confirm_lineup, pList);

    list =  (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_confirm_lineup);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);   // HERE NullPointerException

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

This is the layout of my Dialogfragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_progressdialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Formazione creata"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_confirm_lineup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:divider="#575555"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button_confirm_lineup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Conferma"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list is null because you're trying to get the View from the Activity layout instead of the one of the Dialog.

Try to keep a reference of the Dialog view and get it from there:

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_lineup_layout, null);
// some code
list =  (ListView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.list_confirm_lineup);
```

Answer (score 0):

I update your method

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_lineup_layout, null);
        builder.setView(v);

        pList.add(new ItemLineUpConfirm("P", "C. Abbiati", "MIL", "INT"));
        pList.add(new ItemLineUpConfirm("D", "C. Papastapopulos", "SAS", "VER"));
        pList.add(new ItemLineUpConfirm("C", "Cacca", "SAM", "GEN"));

        adapter = new AdapterListConfirmLineUp(CurrentContext.getContext(), R.layout.item_confirm_lineup, pList);

        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_confirm_lineup);

        list.setAdapter(adapter); // HERE NullPointerException

        return builder.create();
    }
```

The problem was you are trying to find the listview from activity but it is actually in alertbuilder view. So I just change that.

Comment: But what is the problem? mention please in your answer.